# Alternative method of invoking an XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

Probably the most simple way of invoking an XSL stylesheet is by adding a second line to any XML-file, something like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourstylesheet.xsl"?>
```

However, I've heard about other methods - preferably a method that does not require any tampering with the XML-file and not tied up to any particular platform (open format solution).

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

/Paul

---

```
<?php
// Load XML file
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('cdcatalog.xml');

// Load XSL file
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('cdcatalog.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

// Attach the xsl rules
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
?>
```

Comment: I am curious: how may the other methods look like?

Comment: I don't know, but I could have a guess. Probably there is some kind of script running on a server pointing/monitoring what's happening in a certain directory and when an XML-file is opened, then the stylesheet is applyed. So I guess it is a scriptbased solution.

Comment: I found something here. Haven't tried it yet, but it might work: (Don't know how to make it look nice in a comment....will put it in the question it self)

Comment: Thanks for including your solution in your question, but your PHP code isn't easier/shorter than adding a line to an XML file, isn't it?

Comment: No, that's true, but if the intention is to long-term preserve XML-files for decades, then avoiding adding external references into each one of them is desirable.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for solutions for invoking an XSLT transformation server-side from PHP code, or is this just an example?

Comment: Yes I am interested in serverside solution (not ASP) where the file above "cdcatalog.xml" could be set as a variable with the value of currently clicked XML-file (given all is located in the same folder).